# Excel function to compare cell value with other cells values and then get the row number to sum other column to the same raw

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a variable "Red cell - G4" this cell value is changing by time ... i need to make a function to check the cell  "G4" value with all the cells in the "red column - "C7:C260". and then take the raw number and make a sum for all cells above this raw at column E.

Ex: the cell value G4 is the same value of the cell C54 so i need to go to column E and sum all values from E2 to E53

Ex2:the cell value G4 is the same value of the cell C67 so i need to go to column E and sum all values from E2 to E67 [my sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ot4E.png)

Comment: Really unclear, please provide us with expected result and what you've tried/researched

Comment: i have a variable "Red cell - G4" this cell value is changing by time ... i need to make a function to check the cell "G4" value with all the cells in the "red column - "C7:C260". and then take the raw number and make a sum for all cells above this raw at column E.

Ex: the cell value G4 is the same value of the cell C54 so i need to go to column E and sum all values from E2 to E53

Ex2:the cell value G4 is the same value of the cell C67 so i need to go to column E and sum all values from E2 to E67